# Evaluating result of boost::phoenix::insert

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion, boost-phoenix

I'm having difficulties trying to evaluate the result of `boost::phoenix::insert` which inserts elements into a map. Similar to the regular `std::map::insert` the actor object returned by `boost::phoenix::insert` also returns a `std::pair<Iterator where, bool result>`. I'm interested in the second element of that pair to check if the insert was successful. A heavily striped down code example illustrating the issue is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/all.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>

int main(int, char*[])
{
  namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
  using phx::arg_names::arg1;
  using phx::arg_names::arg2;

  std::map<int, int> map;
  std::pair<int, int> value(1, 2);

  if (phx::at_c<1>(phx::insert(arg1, arg2))(map, value)) // <- Error here
    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "Fail" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error using MSVC2012 and boost 1.53:

```
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const bool' to 'bool &'
<some-path>\include\boost\proto\transform\call.hpp:258
```

clang3.2 reports the same error:

```
Compilation finished with errors:
In file included from source.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/phoenix/fusion.hpp:14:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/phoenix/fusion/at.hpp:14:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/phoenix/core/expression.hpp:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/phoenix/core/as_actor.hpp:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/phoenix/core/actor.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/phoenix/core/domain.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/proto/matches.hpp:43:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/proto/transform/when.hpp:22:
/usr/local/include/boost/proto/transform/call.hpp:255:24: error: binding of reference to type 'bool' to a value of type 'const bool' drops qualifiers
                return typename detail::poly_function_traits<Fun, Fun(a0, a1)>::function_type()(
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/phoenix/core/meta_grammar.hpp:74:24: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::proto::call<boost::proto::functional::at (boost::phoenix::evaluator (*)(boost::proto::_child_c<1>), boost::proto::_value (*)(boost::proto::_child_c<0>))>::impl2<const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::at_c, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<mpl_::int_<1> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::detail::tag::function_eval, boost::proto::argsns_::list3<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::stl::insert>, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0> > >, 3> > >, 2> > &, boost::phoenix::vector3<const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::at_c, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<mpl_::int_<1> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::detail::tag::function_eval, boost::proto::argsns_::list3<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::stl::insert>, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0> > >, 3> > >, 2> > *, std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > > &, std::pair<int, int> &> &, const boost::phoenix::default_actions &, false>::operator()' requested here
                return what()(e, phoenix::env(s), actions(s));
                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/phoenix/core/meta_grammar.hpp:34:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::phoenix::evaluator::impl<const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::at_c, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<mpl_::int_<1> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::detail::tag::function_eval, boost::proto::argsns_::list3<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::stl::insert>, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0> > >, 3> > >, 2> > &, const boost::phoenix::vector2<boost::phoenix::vector3<const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::at_c, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<mpl_::int_<1> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::detail::tag::function_eval, boost::proto::argsns_::list3<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::stl::insert>, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0> > >, 3> > >, 2> > *, std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > > &, std::pair<int, int> &> &, const boost::phoenix::default_actions &> &, boost::proto::envns_::empty_env>::operator()' requested here
        BOOST_PROTO_TRANSFORM(evaluator)
        ^
/usr/local/include/boost/proto/transform/impl.hpp:228:9: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PROTO_TRANSFORM'
        BOOST_PROTO_TRANSFORM_(PrimitiveTransform, void)                                                        \
        ^
/usr/local/include/boost/proto/transform/impl.hpp:213:16: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PROTO_TRANSFORM_'
        return boost::proto::detail::apply_transform<transform_type(Expr const &, State const &)>()(e, s, d);   \
               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/phoenix/core/meta_grammar.hpp:139:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::phoenix::evaluator::operator()<const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::at_c, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<mpl_::int_<1> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::detail::tag::function_eval, boost::proto::argsns_::list3<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::stl::insert>, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0> > >, 3> > >, 2> > &, const boost::phoenix::vector2<boost::phoenix::vector3<const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::at_c, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<mpl_::int_<1> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::detail::tag::function_eval, boost::proto::argsns_::list3<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::stl::insert>, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0> > >, 3> > >, 2> > *, std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > > &, std::pair<int, int> &> &, const boost::phoenix::default_actions &> &>' requested here
        return e(expr, ctx);
               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/phoenix/core/detail/preprocessed/actor_operator_10.hpp:31:385: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::phoenix::eval<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::at_c, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<mpl_::int_<1> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::detail::tag::function_eval, boost::proto::argsns_::list3<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::stl::insert>, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0> > >, 3> > >, 2> >, boost::phoenix::vector2<boost::phoenix::vector3<const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::at_c, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<mpl_::int_<1> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::detail::tag::function_eval, boost::proto::argsns_::list3<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::stl::insert>, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0> > >, 3> > >, 2> > *, std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > > &, std::pair<int, int> &> &, const boost::phoenix::default_actions &> >' requested here
        template <typename This, typename A0 , typename A1> struct result<This(A0 & , A1 &)> : result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 & , A1 &> {}; template <typename A0 , typename A1> typename result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 & , A1 &>::type operator()(A0 & a0 , A1 & a1) const { typedef vector3< const actor<Expr> *, A0 & , A1 & > env_type; env_type env = {this, a0 , a1}; return phoenix::eval(*this, phoenix::context(env, default_actions())); } template <typename A0 , typename A1> typename result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 & , A1 &>::type operator()(A0 & a0 , A1 & a1) { typedef vector3< const actor<Expr> *, A0 & , A1 & > env_type; env_type env = {this, a0 , a1}; return phoenix::eval(*this, phoenix::context(env, default_actions())); } template <typename This, typename A0 , typename A1> struct result<This(A0 & , A1 const&)> : result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 & , A1 const&> {}; template <typename A0 , typename A1> typename result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 & , A1 const&>::type operator()(A0 & a0 , A1 const& a1) const { typedef vector3< const actor<Expr> *, A0 & , A1 const& > env_type; env_type env = {this, a0 , a1}; return phoenix::eval(*this, phoenix::context(env, default_actions())); } template <typename A0 , typename A1> typename result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 & , A1 const&>::type operator()(A0 & a0 , A1 const& a1) { typedef vector3< const actor<Expr> *, A0 & , A1 const& > env_type; env_type env = {this, a0 , a1}; return phoenix::eval(*this, phoenix::context(env, default_actions())); } template <typename This, typename A0 , typename A1> struct result<This(A0 const& , A1 &)> : result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 const& , A1 &> {}; template <typename A0 , typename A1> typename result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 const& , A1 &>::type operator()(A0 const& a0 , A1 & a1) const { typedef vector3< const actor<Expr> *, A0 const& , A1 & > env_type; env_type env = {this, a0 , a1}; return phoenix::eval(*this, phoenix::context(env, default_actions())); } template <typename A0 , typename A1> typename result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 const& , A1 &>::type operator()(A0 const& a0 , A1 & a1) { typedef vector3< const actor<Expr> *, A0 const& , A1 & > env_type; env_type env = {this, a0 , a1}; return phoenix::eval(*this, phoenix::context(env, default_actions())); } template <typename This, typename A0 , typename A1> struct result<This(A0 const& , A1 const&)> : result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 const& , A1 const&> {}; template <typename A0 , typename A1> typename result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 const& , A1 const&>::type operator()(A0 const& a0 , A1 const& a1) const { typedef vector3< const actor<Expr> *, A0 const& , A1 const& > env_type; env_type env = {this, a0 , a1}; return phoenix::eval(*this, phoenix::context(env, default_actions())); } template <typename A0 , typename A1> typename result_of::actor<proto_base_expr, A0 const& , A1 const&>::type operator()(A0 const& a0 , A1 const& a1) { typedef vector3< const actor<Expr> *, A0 const& , A1 const& > env_type; env_type env = {this, a0 , a1}; return phoenix::eval(*this, phoenix::context(env, default_actions())); }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ^
source.cpp:16:44: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::at_c, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<mpl_::int_<1> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::detail::tag::function_eval, boost::proto::argsns_::list3<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::stl::insert>, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0> > >, 3> > >, 2> >::operator()<std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >, std::pair<int, int> >' requested here
  if (phx::at_c<1>(phx::insert(arg1, arg2))(map, value))
                                           ^
1 error generated.
```

I'm about to run out of ideas how to correctly evaluating the result of insert. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
The wider context of my question is that I'm trying to parse a C++ like enumeration using boost::spirit::qi. Any examples I found which try to achieve the same do not check for duplicate enumeration members. Here a code snip with the two relevant rules:

```
  enumerationMember = identifier[at_c<0>(_val) = _1] >
    // If there is an explicit value defined use it.
    ((lit('=') > int_[at_c<1>(_val) = _1]) |
    // Otherwise use the value of argument _r1 instead.
    eps[at_c<1>(_val) = _r1]);
  enumeration = lit("enum") > typeName[at_c<0>(_val) = _1] > lit(':') >
    enumerationType[at_c<1>(_val) = _1] > braceOpen >
    // Initialize _a with 0.
    eps[_a = 0] >
    // Zero or one comma separated list of members.
    -(enumerationMember(_a)[//_pass = boost::phoenix::at_c<1>( <- I'm looking for something like this..
      insert(at_c<2>(_val), _1)]
      // Set _a to the value of the last member + 1.
      [_a = at_c<1>(_1) + 1]
      % lit(',')) >
    braceClose;
```

Comment: I believe you should use boost::fusion::at_c. Like [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4C8nzP$4).

Comment: I don't think this is an option because its not me calling the actor object but some boost::spirit::qi parser rule. I'll add that context to my question.

Comment: Right, then you can use it like [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4C8nzP$5). The only change is in the ubication of the parentheses. In a semantic action you won't need the `()` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments of @llonesmiz I found a workaround. The core issue seems to be that arguments are not passed correctly throughout nested actions (or that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong with boost::phoenix):

phx::at_c<1>(phx::insert(arg1, arg2))(map, value)

where the action returned by `at_c` should forward the two arguments map and value to the action returned by `insert`.

In contrast, the following does work:

phx::at_c<1>(phx::insert(arg1, arg2)(map, value))()

However, within a boost::spirit::qi parser I do not have direct access to map because it is one of my return values and I need lazy evaluation (which is the whole point of boost::phoenix anyway). So it doesn't seem to be directly applicable to this (simplified) parser rule:

```
  enumeration = lit("enum") > typeName[at_c<0>(_val) = _1] > braceOpen >
    // Initialize _a with 0.
    eps[_a = 0] >
    // Zero or one comma separated lists of members.
    -(enumerationMember(_a)
      // Only pass if the new member is unique.
      [_pass = at_c<1>(insert(at_c<2>(_val), _1))] // <- Error
      // Set _a to the value of the last member + 1.
      [_a = at_c<1>(_1) + 1]
      % lit(',')) >
    braceClose;
```

The workaround I found is to use two semantic actions and to temporarily store the result of insert into a local variable:

```
  enumeration = lit("enum") > typeName[at_c<0>(_val) = _1] > braceOpen >
    // Initialize _a with 0.
    eps[_a = 0] >
    // Zero or one comma separated lists of members.
    -(enumerationMember(_a)
      // Temporarily store the result of insert into the local variable _b.
      [_b = insert(at_c<2>(_val), _1)]
      // Only pass if the previous insert was successful.
      [_pass = at_c<1>(_b)]
      // Set _a to the value of the last member + 1.
      [_a = at_c<1>(_1) + 1]
      % lit(',')) >
    braceClose;
```

Definition of the rule named `enumeration` now looks like this:

```
boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, Enumeration(),
  boost::spirit::qi::locals<
    int, // _a
    std::pair<std::map<std::string, int>::iterator, bool> // _b
  >, space_type> enumeration;
```

I guess there is some more elegant way than using a local storage for the result of insert. Thus I'll keep this question open for now to allow more elegant answers.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't fully understand your question when I made those comments. Now I see your problem and I'm afraid I don't know how to solve it. Hopefully someone who knows more will help. For "fun" I implemented an enum parser that doesn't use phoenix. You can see it [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3KfI0r$5) (if you change the final loop at the end it should compile without the need of c++11).

Comment: Your comments were still helpful, thanks :) Looking at your approach I'm not quite sure yet whether it is a good decision to put logic into the AST structures or to better keep as much as possible in the parser rules. I see several pros and cons for both approaches. Well, I need to get some more experience with boost::spirit & co, right now I'm still in "experimental stage" :)

Comment: [Last version](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3KfI0r$22). Using `typedef std::map<std::string,int> EnumMember` and putting `current` as a static variable inside `push_back_container::call`.

Comment: There was another version on LWS, which I guess was yours, that parsed the string correctly but didn't fill the map. [Here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3KfI0r$29) is a working version of that, that uses operator `%=` to force attribute propagation when there are semantic actions.

Comment: Yeh I didn't fork the workspace right away, sry :) Your last version is pretty much the same as what I got by now. I prefer to store the "auto value" for new members directly in the parser rule as a local variable (_a), rather than storing it within the AST structure. The alternative of putting it into some static variable prevents multi-threaded parallel parsing of different input streams. However, specializing `push_back_container` for my custom data type works really well and even though its more code it is still more readable than the phoenix magic from above.

Comment: As these comment upvotes do not give you reputation, feel free to post it as a workaround answer. Even though it doesn't answer the original question (which I still couldn't figure out how to do) I could at least upvote it and give you credit for your help.

Comment: Just a minor thing, since you are deriving from std::map you don't need to specialize neither `is_container` nor `container_value`.